# How to change the locale in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, locale

I know this probably looks like a duplicate question but I am unable to change my locale using moment in  my React/ES6 setup.

This is what I have been able to gather from the internet but it doesn't work

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/min/locales';

moment.locale('en-gb');
moment('31/08/2021').format('YYYY-MM-DD') \\ returns 'Invalid Date'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's a locale problem. Can you specify parsing format in method ? 
moment('31/08/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') ?

Comment: @the-juju  I just have the locale info, not the format. Otherwise, it's easy peasy and I wouldn't have had to post a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the perfect way to do it but it definitely works.

```
    locale = 'en-GB';
    value = '07/06/2021';


    moment.locale(locale);
    const localeData = moment.localeData();
    const format = localeData.longDateFormat('L');
    console.log(moment(value, format).format('YYYY-MM-DD')); // '2021-06-07'
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a moment locale issue. Try specifying the right input format to parse a moment string.

More info can be found at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

```js
console.log(moment("31/08/2021", "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
moment('31/08/2021', 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: I don't know the format, I just know the locale.

Comment: You need the format if you string does not match the norm. From the Docs:
When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of new Date(string) if a known format is not found.

Have a look here:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/